# Does Oracle Allow you to simply supply the expected data types for a RECORD without Declaring the Record within a Procedure Call?

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, oracle11g, record

Similar to the work done in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675046/how-to-work-with-pl-sql-arrays-or-collections-as-parameters-then-join-them-toget) I am curious to know if it is possible to do something similar with composite data types.

**Example of what I'm attempting but have never seen it work.**

```
/* Is it possible somehow to instead do THIS? */
tst_proc_rec_type(p_rec    =>  (sys.odcivarchar2list('dan','bob')
                              , sys.odcivarchar2list('anderson','bebop'))
);
```

For some reason I keep returning to this concept and over the years I've never seen a way to get this to work... most likely due to the fact that it's simply NOT possible but I decided to reach out to the community in hopes that perhaps it IS possible and maybe I'm simply doing it wrong. (Wouldn't be the first time).

**Example of working code AND altered code showing what I'm trying to do.**

```
DECLARE

  TYPE t_tst_rec IS RECORD (
    fname   sys.odcivarchar2list,
    lname   sys.odcivarchar2list
  );

  iamrecord   t_tst_rec; /* Declare record of type t_tst_rec */

PROCEDURE tst_proc_rec_type(p_rec t_tst_rec)
IS

BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1..p_rec.lname.COUNT
  LOOP

    dbms_output.put_line(p_rec.lname(i) ||', ' || p_rec.fname(i));

  END LOOP;

END;

BEGIN

  iamrecord.fname :=  sys.odcivarchar2list('dan','bob');
  iamrecord.lname :=  sys.odcivarchar2list('anderson','bebop');

  tst_proc_rec_type(p_rec    =>  iamrecord
  );

  /* Is it possible somehow to instead do THIS? */
--  tst_proc_rec_type(p_rec    =>  (sys.odcivarchar2list('dan','bob')
--                                , sys.odcivarchar2list('anderson','bebop'))
--  );

END;
```

**See it in action.**

[image]

Comment: So far this isn't looking good.. until I hear otherwise... this is NOT possible... no matter how I manipulate the code... I guess I MUST declare the record outside of my Procedure call in order to pass the record into my procedure... I am trying to get away from having to Declare the Types prior to making the Call... I simply want to perform the call and 'Write' in my types directly in the call... as one can do in other programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be dealing with an object type in order to have a constructor of this kind. Simple record types have no such ability. For example, the following would work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_tst_rec AS OBJECT
(
   fname sys.odcivarchar2list,
   lname sys.odcivarchar2list,
   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_tst_rec
   (
      fname sys.odcivarchar2list,
      lname sys.odcivarchar2list
   ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_tst_rec AS

   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_tst_rec
   (
      fname sys.odcivarchar2list,
      lname sys.odcivarchar2list
   ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
   BEGIN
      self.fname := fname;
      self.lname := lname;
      RETURN;
   END t_tst_rec;

END;
/

DECLARE
   iamrecord t_tst_rec; /* Declare record of type t_tst_rec */

   PROCEDURE tst_proc_rec_type(p_rec t_tst_rec) IS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. p_rec.lname.count LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(p_rec.lname(i) || ', ' || p_rec.fname(i));
      END LOOP;
   END;

BEGIN
   tst_proc_rec_type(t_tst_rec(sys.odcivarchar2list('dan', 'bob')
                              ,sys.odcivarchar2list('anderson', 'bebop')));

END;
/
```

Reference for the [lack of a RECORD type constructor syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#sthref1191).

Comment: Funny because I began with OBJECT Types... but couldn't get it to work in a stand alone PL/SQL Block... Is it possible to work with OBJECT Types without first compiling them inside your database?  From what I can tell based on what I have tried this is NOT possible.  Thoughts?

Comment: Object Types need to be created in a schema. You can't create / declare them locally in a anonymous pl/sql block.

Comment: @D.Mika Is this the same for Packages?  It seems I am unable to declare a custom type within a Package whether I try to work it out in the Package Spec or the Body... the custom TYPE itself has it's OWN Body and so I'm thinking that no matter what this is ONLY able to be compiled at the Schema level ONLY.  Again... is this true for Packages as well as far as you are aware?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Object types are only possible at schema level. In a Package you can declare record types, array types or subtypes.